# Sensible small Python example using locks with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I am searching for a sensible (i.e. it should really be useful in terms of efficiency) example using python threads & locks. I know many standard small examples but they are all missing at least one of the properties "small", "sensible" or "using locks" -- for example:

- Testing a list of URLs to check availability (sensible, small, but uses no locks)
- Implementing a few clients (one per thread) and a server holding a variable (or bank account or something alike) -- small, uses locks, but not sensible (in practice there are better ways to implement this).
- Parallelzing a simple algorithm via threads (like the summation of a large list) -- small, but both not sensible (cause you wouldnt parallelize via threads) and not using locks.

Comment: Perhaps 'sensible' and 'using locks' are mutually exclusive?

Comment: This is a great question because it points up the essential issue:  Threads are not often helpful.  Sensible examples are hard to find because multi-processing and message queues (or pipes) is almost always a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python's Queue module](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/Queue.py?view=markup) is a great example of small, yet, synchronized efficient implementation of a queue for the [producer/consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) problem.

Answer (score 4):

Doug Hellmann's page is always a good address to get some examples:

For threading in general:
http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/threading/index.html

Or if you may prefer multiprocessing (e.g. the GIL hits you, or you like to distribute your load over multiple processors):
http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/index.html